# Wrong page count in a tag badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, user-interface

Joshua Weinberg is the sixtieth user to receive [the silver badge for the objective-c tag](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/100). The tag badge page shows at most sixty users at once and, since there are exactly 60 users who’ve received that badge, it should be one page only.

However:

[image]

and clicking [2](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/100?page=2) leads to an empty page.

Comment: +1 for nice catch! It happens every time the users amount divides exactly with 60 even [here](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/7?page=883) - 52920 users, last page empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, this will be fixed in the next build.  The paging system here was being created in an unusual and incorrect way...it's now in-line with the rest of the site.