# Make [tag-page] a synonym of [tags-page]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

It seems that [tag-page](/questions/tagged/tag-page) and [tags-page](/questions/tagged/tags-page) mean exactly the same thing. Currently there are 15 questions for the former tag and 1 question for the latter.

I think that either one of these tags should become a synonym of the other one.
I don't have enough (what SE calls) 'reputation', so therefor I ask for an appropriate synonym to be considered via this question.

**Note**: a tag like [badges-page](/questions/tagged/badges-page) doesn't seem to exist yet, which I think is worth creating also. And searching for tags containing "badges" doesn't seem to result in any appropriate tag either. By creating such tag, probably a lot of [questions currently tagged with [tag:badges], and containing the word 'page'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=[badges]%20page) would be candidate for retagging to such new tag, e.g. for questions like these (with '(..)' to indicate current nr of votes):

- [Should the badge list page be redesigned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72744) (40)
- [Who broke the Badges page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187955) (17)
- [Wrong page count in a tag badge page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110757) (11).

... Should I create a separate question related to this "note"?

Comment: @Mat: do I need to know/understand what the "that" is (was) that you are referring to? Maybe some prior comment that got deleted in the meantime (but which I haven't seen)?

Comment: Yes, someone commented that the tags were already synonyms.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying, and indeed via http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms I just saw that such synonym got created by animuson. I'd appreciate if anybody could advise me on what to do with my "note" part now: leave as such, or move it to a separate (new) question? I'm sorry: so much things/rules etc to be aware of, discover and remember ...

Comment: I really wouldn't bother for the second part (but that's just me). Maybe pop into chat to see if someone would create the tag, if you want to do that retagging. But I don't see a lot of value there, and a lot of bumping old questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though [tags-page](/questions/tagged/tags-page) only has 1 question using it, its name is consistent with the [users-page](/questions/tagged/users-page). For that (consistency) reason, I'd make [tag-page](/questions/tagged/tag-page) a synonym of [tags-page](/questions/tagged/tags-page). The other way around would be my 2<sup>nd</sup> choice.

Answer (score -1):

As the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag implies, this request was completed on April 21, 2015. You can see the results on the [Tag Synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

[image: tags-page <- tag-page]